# Possibility to return child method from parent class method?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue

As I am pretty new to Laravel I am currently using the queue and have the following issue with a job.
Because the API I am calling can throttle, I need to have that logic for every method I call, so I created a parent (base) class. (not sure if this is the right way, please correct me if wrong here as well)

So I have the `JobClass` that extends the `BaseJobClass`, which should handle creation of the API client.

BaseJob

```
class BaseJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    protected function performActionOrThrottle($method, $parameters, Customer $customer, Marketplace $marketplace) {
        $client = $this->createClient($customer, $marketplace);
        if (!method_exists($client, $method)) {
            return $this->fail(new \Exception("Method {$method} does not exist in " . get_class($client)));
        }
        try {
            $result = $client->{$method}($parameters);
        } catch (\Exception $exception)
        {
            echo $exception->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
            return $this->release(static::THROTTLE_LIMIT);
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Job

```
class Job extends BaseJob
{

    CONST THROTTLE_LIMIT = 60;
    CONST RETRY_DELAY = 10;

    private $customer;
    private $requestId;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Customer $customer, $requestId = null)
    {
        $this->customer = $customer;
        $this->requestId = $requestId;
        echo "Updating Inventory for {$customer->name}\n";
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $marketplace = Marketplace::findOrFail(5);

        if (!$report = $this->performActionOrThrottle('GetReport', $this->requestId, $this->customer, $marketplace)) {
            echo "Report not available, trying again in " . self::RETRY_DELAY;
            return $this->release(self::RETRY_DELAY);
        }

        ... 
        handle Data
        ...

        return;
    }
}
```

In order do end the job, I need to return the handle() method. How can I return the handle method from the parent method without having to check for the return value and implementing to return it? If I would to so, there is no point for having that parent that should contain all the logic I need for several jobs.

Comment: check below url

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31883685/laravel-5-1-return-data-from-jobs?rq=1

Comment: parent cannot call the function of the child which is not in the parent. You can declare an empty function in the parent class which will be overridden by the child classes

Comment: @NirajSavaliya sorry but that doesn't have to do anything with my problem. I want to return to stop the excecution, not to return a value.
@DanyalSandeelo what would be the point? I dont want to implement the `createClient` and throttle logic in every job